# Using malloc to allocate memory for an array

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management

I'm trying to make an array of structs by using malloc to allocate the memory needed like so:

```
typedef struct stud{
   char stud_id[MAX_STR_LEN];
   char stud_name[MAX_STR_LEN];
   Grade* grd_list;
   Income* inc_list;
}Stud;

Stud* students = malloc(sizeof(Stud)*STUDENT_SIZE);
```

The problem is that I have a function that adds `id` and `name` to a place in the array like so:

```
void new_student(Stud* students[], int stud_loc){
   scanf("%s", students[stud_loc]->stud_id);
   printf("%s", students[stud_loc]->stud_id);
   scanf("%s", students[stud_loc]->stud_name);
   printf("%s", students[stud_loc]->stud_name); 
}
```

But after the first call to the function, which works, the second one gives me the error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And I can only think that it must mean I'm not doing this right and all the memory is probably going into one place and not in an array form. I'd rather do

```
  Stud students[STUDENT_SIZE];
```

but in this case I must use malloc.

I tried using calloc but I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you (not) check the return value of `malloc()`?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. I'd like to see how you passed a `Stud*` value to a function that takes `Stud*[]`.

Comment: `new_student(Stud* students[], ...` is equal to `new_student(Stud** students, ...`. But you want `new_student(Stud* students,...`. The compiler should have warned you about this.

Comment: Ok i must have misunderstood you, but your answer seem to solve something im testing it right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a mismatch between the local variable `Stud *students` and the function parameter `Stud *students[]`. Those two variables ought to have the same type.

The local variable and `malloc()` look good. `new_student` has an undesirable extra layer of pointers. It should look like this instead:

```
void new_student(Stud* students, int stud_loc){
   scanf ("%s", students[stud_loc].stud_id);
   printf("%s", students[stud_loc].stud_id);
   scanf ("%s", students[stud_loc].stud_name);
   printf("%s", students[stud_loc].stud_name); 
}
```

You would then call it like so:

```
Stud* students = malloc(sizeof(Stud)*STUDENT_SIZE);

new_student(students, 0);
new_student(students, 1);
new_student(students, 2);
```